# C++ template operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm getting a compile error

"conversion from 'int*' to non-scalar type 'foo< int>' requested"

What am i doing wrong?

```
template <typename T> 
struct foo {
  T *ptr;
  foo(void){}
  foo<T>& operator =(const T &point) {
    if (ptr != &point) {
  ptr = &point;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  T& operator*() {
    return *ptr;
  }
}

int main(){
  int x;        
  foo<int> f = &x;  //error here
  *f = 0;
  printf("%d\n", *f)
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB begin with indentation

Comment: sorry for the typing fail,  inconsistent use of ptr errors corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on the line indicated is that you have type mismatch between the variable `f` and its initializer:

```
foo<int> f = &x;
```

The variable has type `foo<int>` while the initializer is of type `int*` and `foo<int>` doesn't have a constructor taking an `int*` as argument. Note that the equal sign in variable definition indicates initialization, not assignment.

Note that the code has more problems, though. Many of them are related to inconsistent use of the `ptr` identifier (sometimes as a member variable, sometimes as a function, sometimes as a type), to invalid use of `&` and more type mismatch errors.

Comment: but shouldn't the operator overload function take care of that?
ptr<T>& operator =(const T &point)

"&x" is indeed a (const T &)  so why doesn't the compiler pick up that overload?

Comment: You're not assigning to a variable on that line. You're initializing it.

Comment: Ah, thanks, i didn't realize that.

I also didn't realize that i had failed so hard at retyping the code.  I'll fix the typing errors.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your compilation error; as to whether it does what you want, it prints zero, so I would presume that's a yes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
struct foo {
  T *ptr;
  foo(void) {};
  foo(T* p) { ptr = p; };

  T*& operator =(const T &point) {
    if (ptr != &point) {
      ptr = &point;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  T& operator*() {
    return *ptr;
  }
};

int main(){
  int x;
  foo<int> f = &x;
  *f = 0;
  printf("%d\n", *f);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i was about to edit my post to include the fixed code and then you posted this.  :)